# How do I fix my broken sourcelinks after moving my website?

Tags: wordpress

Hi I've archived and moved my website to a different url, but now the images and other assets have broken links. instead of the usual "domain.ext/app/wp_content" or "domain.ext/uploads" my links look like "domain.extapp/wp_content" or "domain.extapp/uploads" It's missing the forward slash between the extension and "app".

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Velvet Blues Update URLs" plugin in wordpress and replace your old url format to new url.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't change a thing unfortunately

Comment: There's also Better search replace plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your database .sql file.

1> Open your .sql file, search for the " domain.extapp/wp_content " and replace with " domain.ext/app/wp_content " and upload it.

2> Or simply use the various plugin like "velvet blue url" to change change the urls.

use any of the above process but dont forget to save the permalink in the end.

Comment: Where can I find this file?

Comment: for the first point you need to open your phpmyadmin, then go to export, and export your .sql file

Comment: Done the .sql option, but it didn't change anything. The URL/link is still wrong.

Comment: how you are replacing? can you tell me

Comment: I've searched for the term "devapp" and "dev//////app" and replaced these with "dev/app" in the .sql file before uploading it

Comment: no, dont do this.....search for domain.extapp/ " and replace with " domain.ext/app/ " and upload it.